# AWS EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and the question may seem very basic. However I need to see if I can find a solution to this.

I have created and launched an EC2 instance first and then created an Elastic Beanstalk instance with a sample application deployed on it. By default, the Elastic Beanstalk attaches "Default Environment" to this instance and I find no way to change this to my EC2 instance. How can I attach my EC2 instance (that I created earlier) to this Elastic Beanstalk instance? I am using Amazon Free Tier to learn.

Thanks a lot for your time and patience.

Comment: @edward-samuel this post appears to be specifically about Elastic Beanstalk - your edit could in fact change ELB to EB

Comment: Please clarify if ELB mans Elastic Load Balancer or not? If you mean Elastic Beanstalk, then please use EB. I'm not sure if it's possible to add an instance to an existing beanstalk environment, it's just not matching with the practice. If you want a multi node Beanstalk environment, the scale up the number of instances from the Beanstalk settings page.

Comment: I reset to Elastic Beanstalk, but the question is still unclear so my edit might be incorrect. @Chandra -- could you please explain why you want to attach your EC2 instance to Elastic Beanstalk? People normally use one or the other, but not both together. Unless you are wanting a Load Balancer?

Comment: Yes, I meant Elastic BeanStalk by ELB. Sorry if it is not the industry recognized term. Also, I did a bit of research and it looks like it is not possible to attach a beanstalk session to a previously created EC2 instance. So I understand EC2 and EB are meant to be 2 different channels to deploy my application on AWS. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: And thank you so so much for taking time and looking at my query. Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an existing instance into an Elastic Beanstalk configuration.
Under the hood Elastic beanstalk uses Containers and a ton of configuration hooks, files, etc.

An instance is not the same and cannot even be guaranteed to be of matching types (perhaps the instance is CentOS and the Container runs on an ubuntu host).

It's simply not possible.